# What are good diff tools that are self contained and can be used from a 

Tags: windows-xp, diff

What are good diff tools that are self contained (small in size and in as little files as possible), and can be used from an USB with no extra fuss ? Not looking for command line ones.

So far I found diffuse ... any more like it ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a version of the open-source WinMerge which has been optimised for running from a USB stick by the kind folks at [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/winmerge_portable).

I have no idea whether this meets your size/OS requirements.

Answer (score 1):

[VimDiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html)! Vim is available on multiple platforms (including Windows XP) and is able to three-way diffs and merges. Never leave home without it!

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare is absolutely brilliant: http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: If I remember correctly, BC makes a full directory of files when installing. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: All of the extra files in that directory are optional.  If you use the installer to create a portable install you can delete everything except BCompare.exe and BCState.xml and it will still work.  You will lose 7-zip, RAR, and PDF support though.  It does create quite a few (small) settings files though, so you might want to keep it in its own directory.  Also, as long as you have your registration key in the same directory you can compress it with UPX or another exe compressor.